# Two's complement addition overflow in C

Tags: c, debugging

I saw a buggy code in C which was used to check whether addition results in overflow or not. It works fine with `char`, but gives incorrect answer when arguments are `int` and I couldn't figure why .
Here's the code with `short` arguments.

```
short add_ok( short x, short y ){
    short sum = x+y;
    return (sum-x==y) && (sum-y==x);
}
```

This version works fine, problem arise when you change arguments to `int` ( you can check it with `INT_MAX` )
Can you see what's wrong in here ?

Comment: A correct check would be something like `SHRT_MAX - x <= y` or something like that.

Comment: You'll find [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow) the best way to ensure that there are no overflows

Comment: Can you tell what experimental values have you chosen along with short and int sizes in your machine, and what return value did you get? The reason is because it "works in my machine".

Comment: For `int` you can check it with both arguments set as `INT_MAX` .
With `char`, as @R.. says, it doesn't overflow .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in 2s complement, the integers can be arranged into a circle (in the sense of [modulo arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_arithmetic)). Adding y and then subtracting y always gets you back where you started (undefined behaviour notwithstanding).

Comment: @kerrek: not sure of a better way to describe itin one sentence!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Wrap around?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Maybe "ring" :-)

Comment: no, generally not UB, the arithmetic is done as `int` as R.. correctly states.

Comment: So you it's like it keeps track of it and kinda replace it, ha ?
I mean `sum-x` becomes `(x+y)-x` ?

Comment: @jens: luckily, I've carefully worded my answer to avoid all possible contention on this matter!

Comment: @arash take a look at the Wikipedia article on 2s complement, and it should become obvious why this happens.

Comment: oo, and btw, as @Mysticial said, we also call it Abelian group. "Abelian group" is just a fancy mathematical term for a "ring". Two's complement integers with the usual overflow behavior forms a "ring" of integers. When you add/subtract, you shift along the ring. So regardless of overflow, you can always shift back in the opposite direction.

Comment: @ArashThr: By "ring", I didn't really mean a [mathematical ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29); I was referring to the notion of modulo arithmetic; the idea that you can arrange the numbers in a circle like on a clock-face.

Answer (score 5):

In your code, the addition **does not overflow** unless `int` is the same size as `short`. Due to default promotions, `x+y` is performed on the values of `x` and `y` promoted to `int`, and then the result is truncated to `short` in an implementation-defined manner.

Why not do simply: `return x+y<=SHRT_MAX && x+y>=SHRT_MIN;`

Comment: Thanks for this interesting fact about type promotion.  I didn't know that!  C is such a tricky language.

Comment: @airza Read a good book on C, or better yet start reading the C standard. It's never too late to learn how your tools of trade work, and it can be beneficial too.

Answer (score 4):

In C programming language, signed integers when converted to smaller signed integers, say char (for the sake of simplicity), are of implementation-defined manner. Even though many systems and programmers assume wrap-around overflow, it is not a standard. So what is wrap-around overflow?

Wrap-around overflow in Two's complement systems happens such that when a value can no longer be presented in the current type, it warps around the highest or lowest number that can be presented. So what does this mean? Take a look.

In signed char, the highest value that can be presented is 127 and the lowest is -128. Then what happens when we do: "char i = 128", is that the value stored in  i becomes -128. Because the value was larger than the signed integral type, it wrapped around the lowest value, and if it was "char i = 129", then i will contain -127. Can you see it? Whenever an end reaches its maximum, it wraps around the other end (sign). Vice versa,  if "char i = -129", then i will contain 127, and if it is "char i = -130", it will contain 126, because it reached its maximum and wrapped around the highest value.

(highest) 127, 126, 125, ... , -126, -127, -128 (lowest)

If the value is very large, it keeps wrapping around until it reaches a value that can be represented in its range.

[image: wrap-around point for char type]

---

**UPDATE:** the reason why `int` doesn't work in oppose to `char` and `short` is because that when both numbers are added there is a possibility of overflow (regardless of being `int`, `short`, or `char`, while not forgetting integral promotion), but because `"short"` and `char` are with smaller sizes than `int` and because they are promoted to `int` in expressions, they are represented again without truncation in this line:

```
return (sum-x==y) && (sum-y==x);
```

So any overflow is detected as explained later in detail, but when with `int`, it is not promoted to anything, so overflow will happen. For instance, if I do `INT_MAX+1`, then the result is INT_MIN, and if I tested for overflow by INT_MIN-1 == INT_MAX, the the result is TRUE! **This is because "short" and char get promoted to int, evaluated, and then get truncated (overflowed). However, int get overflowed first and then evaluated, because they are not promoted to a larger size.**

Think of char type without promotion, and try to make overflows and check them using the illustration above. You will find it that adding or subtracting values that cause the overflow returns you to where you were. However, this is not what happens in C, because char and "short" are promoted to int, thus overflow is detected, which is not true in int, because it is note promoted to a larger size.

**END OF UPDATE**

---

For your question, I checked your code in MinGW and Ubuntu 12.04, seems to work fine. I found later that the code works actually in systems where short is smaller than int, and when values don't exceed int range. This line:

```
return (sum-x==y) && (sum-y==x);
```

is true, because "sum-x" and "y" are evaluated as (int) so no wrap-around happens to, where it happened in the previous line (when assigned):

```
short sum = x+y;
```

Here is a test. If I entered 32767 for the first and 2 for the second, then when:

```
short sum = x+y;
```

sum will contain -32767, because of the wrap-around. However, when:

```
return (sum-x==y) && (sum-y==x);
```

"sum-x" (-32767 - 32767) will only be equal to y (2) (then buggy) if wrap-round occurs, but because of integral promotion, it never happen that way and "sum-x" value becomes -65534 which is not equal to y, which then leads to a correct detection.

Here is the code I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

short add_ok( short x, short y ){
    short sum = x+y;
    return (sum-x==y) && (sum-y==x);
}

int main(void) {

    short i, ii;
    scanf("%hd %hd", &i, &ii);
    getchar();

    printf("%hd", add_ok(i, ii));

    return 0;
}
```

Check [here](http://ideone.com/lSLwf) and [here](http://ideone.com/AmM4D).

You need to provide the architecture you are working on, and what are the experimental values you tested, because not everyone faces what you say, and because of the implementation-defined nature of your question.

Reference: C99 6.3.1.3 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), and GNU C Manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Integer-Overflow-Basics.html#Integer-Overflow-Basics).

Comment: I changed to question a little, you may want to check again .

Comment: @ArashThr , try to think about it. I updated it and really ran out of words xD

Answer (score 1):

The compiler probably just replaces all calls to this expression with 1 because it's true in every case.  The optimizing routine will perform copy propagation on sum and get

```
return (y==y) && (x==x);
```

and then:

```
return 1
```

It's true in every case because signed integer overflow is undefined behavior- hence, the compiler is free to guarantee that x+y-y == x and y+x-x == y.

If this was an unsigned operation it would fail similarly- since overflow is just performed as a modulo operation it is fairly easy to prove that

```
x+y mod SHRT_MAX - y mod SHRT_MAX == x
```

and similarly for the reverse case.

Comment: So you mean "optimizer" replaces sum in `sum+x` with `x+y` ? also what do you mean by "undefined behavior" ?

Comment: @ArashThr Undefined behaviour is behaviour the standard doesn't place any restriction on. The implementation/compiler is allowed to do whatever it pleases. It can refuse to compile, emit code to format your hard drive, or create code that works as you intended - except if you run it on a Friday, when it will format your hard drive.

Comment: Essentially, the compiler will assume that your code can't produce undefined behavior and optimize appropriately.  If it does (for example, if your integers overflow) you cannot guarantee anything about anything in the program anymore. In practice the results can sometimes be somewhat livable- which doesn't mean you should rely on undefined behavior, but rather that its existence can make some C bugs very insidious.  Like this one.

Comment: Can you give a reference about this "optimizing routine" ?